# fql query for getting images of facebook movie category

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new for fql query.I want to get images of movies,sports etc that i have liked in facebook.If there is another way besides fql query then also tell me.
please help me if anybody knows.

Comment: You mean the images of Facebook Pages for certain movies? Your question is not clear...

Comment: yes movie's profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

For movies you can get a selection at

`me/movies?fields=id,picture.type(large),cover`

For sports, you will have to loop through the `/me/likes` response for the "Sports team" category.